# How to open XML file with Excel?

Tags: c++, windows, xml, excel

I want to develop a small tool which for open XML file and launch Excel automatically.
The benefit for user who could save the excel file to .xls format very conveniently.

My Dev IDE: Windows XP pro & Visual Studio 2005.

The tool will running at Windows 2000 & Excel 2000. and there is no .net framework installed.

That means i can't code with C#. My choice is C++.

Comment: I think your question might be more appropriate for http://www.rentacoder.com/RentACoder/DotNet/default.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Oneliner:

```
int main() {
    system("Start Excel test.xml");
}
```

Comment: We have the sme app in my company, it's called... mm... a human-being =)

Comment: Which reminds me: http://www.thinkgeek.com/tshirts-apparel/unisex/frustrations/374d/

Comment: Hi MSalters,

Good day.

I test like your said. but i really not good effect.
1st. I want to parser my XML with some C++ functions.
2nd. i want to convert the passer result data to .csv.
3rd. i could take user your guide to start my .csv with my Excel file. 

Any more suggestion?
Thank you in advance.
BR
Nano

Comment: Still trivial - read XML (any parser will do), process as desired, write .csv file, call `system("start Excel test.csv");`

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly you want to open an excel file and then auto launch xml editor?

A way is to add a option the the contect menu when rightclicking on the xls file.

Use register for this:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.xls\shell\

create a key (Default) and value something like "Open excel and xml editor"
create a folder "command" and a key (Default) with value "path to your exe" "%L" in that folder.

Then in your app catch the param (which holds the xls)
and then do something like this:

```
system(<var holding the xls name>);
system(<path to xml editor>):
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx). It will automatically start program which associated with certain extension, or you could select program manually.

Answer (score 0):

In C#

OpenXML in MSDN - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.openxml(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.openxml%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

string workbookPath= @"C:\temp\Results_2013Apr02_110133_6692.xml";

            this.lblResultFile.Text = string.Format(@" File:{0}",workbookPath);
            if (File.Exists(workbookPath))
            {
                Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                excelApp.Visible = true;
                Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.OpenXML(workbookPath, Type.Missing, Excel.XlXmlLoadOption.xlXmlLoadPromptUser);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("File:{0} does not exists", workbookPath));
            }
```